# could not update or edit the specific data in the HTTP post method

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I wanted to update the quantity value. for that, I am using the HTTPPost method of the index for update quantity. but it's could not because of error.
here is my code:

```
   
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(_db.Shop.Include(c => c.Category).Include(f => f.SubCategory).ToList());
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Index(int? id)
        {
            var product = _db.Shop.Where(x => x.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();

            IndexVm ji = new IndexVm 
            {
              
                Id = product.Id,
                Image = product.Image,
                Image1 = product.Image1,
                Quantity = product.Quantity++,
                Price = product.Price,
                PreviousPrice = product.PreviousPrice,
                Description = product.Description,
            };

            _db.Shop.Update(ji);
            _db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
```

Index.cshtml

```
    @using Amazon.Models
@model IEnumerable<Shop>


@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
}

<br /><br />

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-6">
        <h2 class="text-info">Product List</h2>
    </div>

    <div class="col-6 text-right">
        <a asp-action="Create" class="btn btn-info">&nbsp;Add New Product </a>
    </div>

</div>

<form asp-action="Create" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">


    <div>
        <table class="table table-striped border" id="myTable">

            <thead>

                <tr class="table-info">
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(c => c.Name)

                    </th>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(c => c.Price)

                    </th>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(c => c.PreviousPrice)

                    </th>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(c => c.Quantity)

                    </th>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(c => c.Description)

                    </th>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(c => c.Quantity)

                    </th>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(c => c.CategoryTypeId)

                    </th>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(c => c.SubCategoryTypeId)

                    </th>

                    <th></th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>



            <tbody>
                @foreach (var item in Model)
                {
                    <tr class="text-info">

                        <td>  @item.Name </td>
                        <td>  @item.Price </td>
                        <td>  @item.PreviousPrice </td>



                        <td>@item.Quantity</td>

                        <td>
                            <partial name="_QuantityPartial" model="@item.Id" />
                        </td>



                        <td>  @item.Description </td>
                        <td>  @item.Size </td>
                        <td>  @item.Category.CategoryName </td>
                        <td>  @item.SubCategory.SubCategoryName </td>


                        <td>
                            <partial name="_DeletePartial" model="@item.Id" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                }





            </tbody>



        </table>
    </div>
</form>
<br /> <br />

@section scripts{

    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#myTable').DataTable();
        });



    </script>

    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        function incrementValue(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var fieldName = $(e.target).data('field');
            var parent = $(e.target).closest('div');
            var currentVal = parseInt(parent.find('input[name=' + fieldName + ']').val(), 10);

            if (!isNaN(currentVal)) {
                parent.find('input[name=' + fieldName + ']').val(currentVal + 1);
            } else {
                parent.find('input[name=' + fieldName + ']').val(0);
            }
        }

        function decrementValue(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var fieldName = $(e.target).data('field');
            var parent = $(e.target).closest('div');
            var currentVal = parseInt(parent.find('input[name=' + fieldName + ']').val(), 10);

            if (!isNaN(currentVal) && currentVal > 0) {
                parent.find('input[name=' + fieldName + ']').val(currentVal - 1);
            } else {
                parent.find('input[name=' + fieldName + ']').val(0);
            }
        }

        $('.input-group').on('click', '.button-plus', function (e) {
            incrementValue(e);
        });

        $('.input-group').on('click', '.button-minus', function (e) {
            decrementValue(e);
        });

    </script>

   
}
```

_QuantityPartial.cshtml

```
@model int

<form method="post">
    <td style="width:150px">
        <div class="btn-group">

            @*<a asp-action="Index"  class="btn btn-danger" asp-route-id="@Model">Add</a>*@
            <input type="submit" asp-action="Index" asp-route-id="@Model" value="+" />
        </div>
    </td>
</form>
```

and here is my output and here is my output below. I want something like that. I actually want when I click "+"  then quantity would be updated. and here is my output below. I want something like that. I actually want when I click "+"  then quantity would be updated. for that here I use the HTTP post method(index) but I found an error. for that, I can not update my quantity data.

[image]
[image]

I am beginner, please anyone help.

Comment: you are having problem with entity `shop`. Pls post your entity here

Comment: and maybe reformat your `Index.cshtml` and also post the header of the file.

Comment: @LongLuong I posted Index.cshtml with header file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing these two mistakes:

1. You are passing VM to update function which is wrong.
2. To update any existing EF object, you have to update that object instead of creating new.

   ```
    {
        var product = _db.Shop.Where(x => x.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();

        product.Quantity++;

        _db.Shop.Update(product);
        _db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }
   ```

Answer (score 2):

You should use:

```
var product = _db.Shop.AsNoTracking().Where(x => x.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();
```

You are fetching product but updating new instance ji with the same id. Since the id is the same, EF thinks that those are two objects with same primary key which should not happen, thus error.

Your other option would be to update product that you fetched from the database:

```
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Index(int? id)
        {
            var product = _db.Shop.Where(x => x.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();
            product.Quantity++;

            _db.Shop.Update(product);
            _db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
```

You can find more about this here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/tracking